# Visio 2010 using a page name in mailto link

Tags: dynamic, visio, mailto

Is it possible to get the name of the current page dynamically and add it to the link?

I am trying to add a "Feedback" button to each page of my visio diagram and want to create a mailto: hyperlink on that shape adding as much information as I can in the link.

So, my link looks like

mailto:TargetMailbox@mycompany.com?subject=Visio%20for%20Standards%20-Question/Comment  **XXXXXXXXXXX**     *Add page name*    **XXXXXXXXXXXXX**&cc=LoggedinUser@mycompany.com&body=I%20have%20a%20question.%0AI%20would%20like%20to%20know

Here, in the subject part - I would like to add the page name of the page from which the "Feedback" button is clicked.

Is this possible?  How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PAGENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765320.aspx) ShapeSheet function as follows:

```
Hyperlink.Row_1.Address ="mailto:TargetMailbox@mycompany.com?subject=Visio%20for%20Standards%20-Question/Comment%20"&PAGENAME()&"&cc=LoggedinUser@mycompany.com&body=I%20have%20a%20question.%0AI%20would%20like%20to%20know"
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked out well for me.  If I may, I had tried to use the PAGENAME function, but didn't know I had to use it in the format "&PAGENAME()&".  Would you mind, explaining what does the pair of "& &" do? Is there any documentation I could refer to regarding how to use these functions embedded into different things as I had tried?  Also, can any other functions be used in similar way?

Comment: PAGENAME() is a ShapeSheet function that returns a string, which is evaluated everytime the page on which the shape sits changes.  So you really have three strings that you need to concatentate/glue togther and that's what the ampersand character does.  You end up with a formula ="firstPart"&PAGENAME()&"endPart". See the bottom of this page for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766119.aspx