# Use a Visio PageName as an Email Subject

Tags: html, hyperlink, visio, mailto

I hate to do this, but I have the same question as the following link: [Visio 2010 using a page name in mailto link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579346/visio-2010-using-a-page-name-in-mailto-link)

I have attempted to use the answer given but all I'm getting is PAGENAME() in the subject field of the generated email. My Visio file is rendered to a html file where this link will be used.

I'd have added a comment to avoid creating a new question but don't have enough Rep to follow up on the comments there.

If anyone can give me a pointer, that'd be great. The line I have at the moment is

>
mailto:my.email@email.com&Subject=PAGENAME()&Body=Text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like I've worked this one out.

I needed to right click the object & head in to the "Show ShapeSheets" window.

Once in here, adjust the 'Hyperlinks' entry: In the 'ExtraInfo' box change:

> ="subject=PAGENAME()"

to

> ="subject="&PAGENAME()

Logical when you look at it.

I do have the problem now that when Visio renders the html files, it doesn't use the foreground PAGENAME() in the same way was when you insert PAGENAME() into an object. The email title is always the background name & not the foreground.

I doubt there'll be a way of resolving that one, but glad I got to see it in action.